# .net activeX equivalent

Tags: .net, activex, client-server, client-side

Is there a pure .NET replacement for ActiveX?  I'm asking if there is a way for me to write a thick client side control to be loaded and interacted with in a web page in .NET, with NO com.

Edit: I don't want ActiveX in pure .NET, I want a .NET alternative to ActiveX.

Comment: See my comments in the other posts. Shay has the correct answer, and there is a tutorial over at http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=187

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no perfect managed only equivalent of ActiveX.  Mostly for good reason.  ActiveX is a dangerous technology security wise and duplicating it's effects in many ways would require duplicating the lack of security.

Have you tried SilverLight?

It's not a perfect ActiveX replacement because it doesn't grant you unferreted access to the machine.  But it does provide the ability to write rich client side controls in .Net.

Comment: @Slough, you can code ActiveX controls in managed code but there is no managed ActiveX.  I believe the user is asking about the latter

Comment: I think I'm missing something. If you code an ActiveX in managed code output won't be native code (or is it something special like Ngen?). If output is not native code that means it's managed. So there is something called managed ActiveX? Am I wrong?

Comment: @Slough, the user asked though "is there a managed *replacement* for ActiveX" not "can I code a ActiveX like client in managed code". The OP may have intended the latter but I read it as the former.  There is no managed framework which replaces ActiveX

Comment: @JaredPar, SilverLight may be the answer in the end, but how stable are the development tools so far?

Comment: @C.Ross, using VS to code silverlight works great. However I work on Visual Studio and own a subset of the SilverLight story so I'm biased :)

Comment: @JaredPar, see http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=187 . He doesn't include ComVisible in the assembly. This is not ActiveX, and BTW all the 'dangerious' aspects of ActiveX have been rectified. And if the control's signatory is trusted it has completed access.

Comment: @Jonathan, having a control with the power of ActiveX and the security problems fixed is simply not possible.  These are mutually exclusive properties.

Comment: @JaredPar, if you work at Microsoft I highly recommend you read up on this. Surely you must understand CAS if you *work on Visual Studio*?

Comment: @JaredPar, and I said, you only have the power of ActiveX if the publisher (assembly signer) is trusted; otherwise you are pretty much in a sandbox.

Comment: @Jonathan, I very much understand CAS. My point is that ActiveX has 0 security. If you add CAS to a managed application you get something that cannot possibly be a 100% ActiveX replacement because it will have limitatations that ActiveX does not.

Comment: (cont) the OP is asking for a managed framework that is an ActiveX replacement. Various managed frameworks exist (with CAS) but they will not ever allow the full range of operations that an ActiveX control had because of the inherent insecurity in doing so.

Comment: @JaredPar, "will not ever allow" is entirely flawed. You can add a publisher rule to your local CAS Policy (using caspol.exe) to grant Full Trust in all situations to a specific publisher. If all of what I say is wish-wash; then how does Unity do what it does?

Comment: @Jonathan I am unfamiliar with Unity. But there is a very basic principal here.  ActiveX's power relies it it's ability to do anything and hence be insecure.  Any security restrictions you place on content creates a new product, not a 100% replacement.  I'm not saying it's impossible to create an ActiveX *like* component.  It's just one of the following must be true 1) Hosted apps are less powerful or 2) they are insecure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) it can be embedded inside IE, I don't know what you mean by interaction with the web browser, but it can call out scripts on the page and post events that can be handled by scripts on the page.
Notice that .NET must be preinstalled in order for the control to work.
You can also go with Silverlight as *JaredPar* mention, but then your api is more limited.

Comment: I found a tutorial http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=187 . Maybe add it to the answer.

Comment: @Jonathan, 10x but this article is outdated (looks like .net v1.0).

Comment: @Shay, it does still apply. If he has access to the policy on client machines (so he can trust his key on them) he should be able to do anything he wants.