# Replacing ActiveX exe with .NET?

Tags: .net, delphi, activex

We have an old ActiveX exe that we provide to third parties to use for a specific purpose.  They take our exe and call it from their own software package to perform the given task (review form documents), then close our app.  We are wanting to get away from the ActiveX exe model, and replace it with a .NET equivalent.  I know that creating an ActiveX exe is not possible with .NET, so what would be an equivalent replacement that still meets our needs?  The calling app must be able to open/close the application and call some of it's methods (add files, delete files, etc).  Is this at all possible with .NET?

Comment: .net has strong COM support. Are you sure you cannot implement what you need with ActiveX? Where does Delphi come into this? Your development platform is .net.

Comment: the original activex exe is written in delphi, so I figured I would ask here hoping that a delphi dev had run into the same issue.

Comment: Sounds like a .net question rather than a Delphi question. I'd lose the Delphi tag. And add whichever .net language you are using.

Comment: Take a look at this old thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748603/net-activex-equivalent

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at RemObject Hydra (http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/), you can mix both platforms with it

Answer (score 1):

Local COM server (also known as: Out of Process COM server, also known as: DCOM) are supported in .NET.
See this (long) article for a sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12579/Building-COM-Servers-in-NET.
Search any of the a.k.a. above with .NET or c# and find many other samples.

EDIT: Here is a sample (short, accurate, walk-through), from Microsoft: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSExeCOMServer-3b1c1054. Use this sample as your starting point.